# How Do I Add a Referenced Library in Cognos CAM Jar?

Tags: java, cognos

I am trying to include a reference to Apache Commons Codec in my custom auth provider for Cognos 10.  I've referenced it correctly in Eclipse and is exported correctly in the JAR file.  I've also copied the apache jar file along with the CAM jar file to the WEB-INF/lib folder.

I get the following error:

> org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.encodeToString([B)Ljava/lang/String;

I don't understand where I've gone wrong.  Can anyone provide help with adding a referenced library to a custom auth provider for Cognos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Cognos has the commons jar and mine was causing a conflict.